# Is there any way to remove mixed content warning from my blogger website after adding affiliate banners?

Tags: https, http, blogger, affiliate, amazon

Is there any way to remove the mixed content warning from my blogger website after adding affiliate banners that are served over HTTP but my website is https? I am trying to add Amazon affiliate banners to my blogger website but it causes a mixed content warning. I tried removing HTTP also replacing it with https but nothing worked. Then I tried contacting them but they also failed to provide me with any solution.

Comment: Did you try replacing http:// with just // ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

As browsers are more and more frowning upon such cases the only real solution is to make sure that all the content is served over HTTPS (more precisely: if the page is served over HTTPS then everything it depends on - fonts, scripts, stylesheets, iframes, etc. - is also served over HTTPS; if the page is server itself over HTTP, the other content can be be served over HTTP or HTTPS just fine, but browsers do also push for HTTPS everywhere).

Latest example: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html

> Today we’re announcing that Chrome will gradually ensure that secure
>   (HTTPS) pages only download secure files. In a series of steps
>   outlined below, we’ll start blocking "mixed content downloads"
>   (non-HTTPS downloads started on secure pages).

This is about content to download from your web page but there is the same trend for all referenced content. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content for details and solutions (which are: replace HTTP links by HTTPS ones).

So you will not get just warnings, but content will stop to load and hence your page will probably not render or work correctly anymore.

Or get bad UI: since 2015 for example, Google Chrome did not report a website as secure, even over HTTPS, if it had problems with HTTP references (see https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/chrome-finally-kills-off-the-http-https-mixed-content-warning/)

Everything else than getting proper HTTPS links everywhere is just putting in place horrible workarounds or delaying the problem few months in the future, so not advisable.

PS: when asking for help, saying "but nothing worked" is not very helpful to the people trying to help you. Because that does not say 1) exactly what you tried (nothing means you tried "everything" and that of course is not possible), 2) how you tried (what commands/actions you did), 3) what exactly you got back (an error? which one? a timeout? a crash? etc.) and 4) what you did expect instead.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue. The solution is really simple but worked for me.
What I did is, as I was using Amazon and flipkart static banners, I downloaded those banners and uploaded them to my website and linked them with my https affiliate link.
Because the issue was with banners only which were served over http, as I checked the code provided by them.